# how to set up SSL on a magento multisite

Tags: magento, ssl, cpanel

We just moved a bunch of our websites from one server to another (obviously changing their IP addresses in the process), some of which were multisites in magento. The domains are not parked, but the multisites work. I don't completely understand how magento works regarding multisites, but that's not necessarily what my question is.

When we moved the websites, the multisites were broken. Eventually, we hired a freelancer to fix the multisites. Last night, i put the entire website package (multisites included) on their own dedicated IP addresses. They're on the same server, in the same place, but they have their own IP address on that server. I just walked in monday morning and SSL is broken on all the multisites, but works on the main website. Can anybody tell me what to do here? I have access to the certificate, bought through a third party. When i try to list the certs in cpanel, it just lists the main website as a "controlled certificate". My question is, why did these work on the original IP address after being transferred to the new server? and how do i set up SSL on the multisites? I have cPanel but im actually an admin that's worked WITHOUT cpanel for many years (not in webhosting). so i dont know much about ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got complex because our server was set up using cPanel, which means it had a bunch of pre-installed programs (like, for example, sendmail, dovecot, etc.) the program that was giving me grief over this issue was suphp. I couldn't figure out how to make the multisites work independently of the parent website. so, say i have www.frattoys.com as the parent and a bunch of child sites that pull from it, like frattanks.com, irontap.com, etc. those child websites share source code with frattoys.com. suphp wasnt allowing frattanks and irontap to pull code from frattoys if they were independent websites; independent cpanel and user accounts. thats why i was trying to install SSL on top of addon or subdomains; hence the question. as it turned out, i ended up uninstalling suphp and replacing it with fastcgi. that way, i could set the permissions to what they needed to be, share the code with frattoys, and install SSL on the child websites without too many issues.

The eventual solution to my problems was to install fastcgi (uninstall suphp), create independent users for each child website, and install SSL certificates from WHM for each child user.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what certificate you have and server config. The only thing in magento you should check is the secure url is https and that it is enabled per each site in the admin. The certificate setup depends on what type of certificate you are using. If it's a wild card/ucc certificate that covers all domains/subdomains then it should simply install the certificate and the issuing authorities certificate, setup vhosts and it should work for all sites. If it's individual certificates per website you will need to install each certificate onto the server but this can be complex.

You also need to configure the apache vhost for each site so there is a host listening on port 443 for each site. there should be an ssl directive poiting to the certificate files. Check the vhost for the working site and compare to the others to see if anything is missing. If individual certificates (i.e. one per each domain) you normally need to have multiple ips for your server, one per each domain.